# How can i set the cookie with path in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, cookie-path

I am trying to set the cookie with path and it is working all browsers except IE.

The code which i am using is

```
$.cookie("selections",sids,{path:'/sme-ist'});
```

This is working in all browsers except in IE.

I was able to set the cookie without the path but i need path also

Please let me know